# cs50 readability pset6 python - Index calculation Issue

Tags: python, cs50, readability

### An Index calculation Issue in my pset6 readability

This is my code and I think it is correct but, the grade for every paragraph is wrong because the index calculation is wrong. Although, the letters, words, and sentence counting is correct. So, where is the problem? someone help me, please?

```
from cs50 import get_string
import math

# Loop to count the letters
letters = 0
words = 0
sentences = 0

# Prompt user for some text.
text = get_string("Text: ")

# Loop to count the letters(s) of a paragraph
def count_letters():
    global letters
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].lower() or text[i].upper():
            letters += 1
            # pass
    print(letters)
    return letters
count_letters()

# Loop to count the words of the paragraph.

def count_words():
    global words
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isspace():
            words += 1
        # TODO
        if text[i].isspace() and text[i + 1].isspace():
            words -= 1
    print(words + 1)
    return words + 1
count_words()

# Loop to count sentences of the paragraph.

def count_sentences():
    global sentences
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] == "." or text[i] == "!" or text[i] == "?":
            sentences += 1
    print(sentences)
    return sentences
count_sentences()

# Calc the index of the grades

def indexOfGrade():
    global letters
    global words
    global sentences
    l = letters / words * 100
    s = sentences / words * 100
    index = round(0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8)
    print(letters / words)
    print(l)
    print(s)
    print(index)

    # grades

    if index >= 16:
        print("Grade 16+")
    elif index < 1:
        print("Before Grade 1")
    else:
        print(f"Grade {index}")

indexOfGrade()
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `index` before printing? Maybe you can print that too. Your calculation looks correct for index but for letters, words and sentences it is hard to tell. I would throw a short sentence to check if counting function are doing the right job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahooo, after a lot of time I figured out your mistake.

```
def count_words():
    global words
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isspace():
            words += 1
        # TODO
        if text[i].isspace() and text[i + 1].isspace():
            words -= 1
    print(words + 1)
    return words + 1 #This part is wrong
```

The last line, which is return will just return the value but will not change the value of the variable words, therefore, you need to correct it as follows

```
def count_words():
    global words
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isspace():
            words += 1
        # TODO
        if text[i].isspace() and text[i + 1].isspace():
            words -= 1
    print(words + 1)
    words += 1
    return words
```

Also the letters, words and sentences variables may optionally be float and not int and while calculating the index, python will omit the remaining decimal part, therefore the round may not work.

Also, I have performed check50 on my device and all the results were green with (correct)

Also, `if text[i].isspace() and text[i + 1].isspace():` was wrong you need to completely delete that part.

Therefore here is the final answer with the required changes.

```
from cs50 import get_string
import math

# Loop to count the letters
letters = float(0)
words = float(0)
sentences = float(0)

# Prompt user for some text.
text = get_string("Text: ")

# Loop to count the letters(s) of a paragraph
def count_letters():
    global letters
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if (text[i] >= 'a' and text[i] <= 'z') or (text[i] >= 'A' and text[i] <= 'Z'):
            letters += 1
            # pass
    # # print(letters)
    return letters
count_letters()

# Loop to count the words of the paragraph.

def count_words():
    global words
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i].isspace():
            words += 1
        # # TODO
        # if text[i].isspace() and text[i + 1].isspace():
        #     pass
    # # print(words + 1)
    words += 1
    return words + 1
count_words()

# Loop to count sentences of the paragraph.

def count_sentences():
    global sentences
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] == "." or text[i] == "!" or text[i] == "?":
            sentences += 1
    # # print(sentences)
    return sentences
count_sentences()

# Calc the index of the grades

def indexOfGrade():
    global letters
    global words
    global sentences
    # print(letters)
    # print(words)
    # print(sentences)
    l = 100 * letters / words
    # print(l)
    s = sentences / words * 100
    # print(s)
    index = round(0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8)
    # # print(letters / words)
    # print(0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8)
    # print(l)
    # print(s)
    # print(index)

    # grades

    if index >= 16:
        print("Grade 16+")
    elif index < 1:
        print("Before Grade 1")
    else:
        print(f"Grade {index}")

indexOfGrade()
```

**Note**: you may optionally remove all the comment statements.

[Link to my check50 result](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/e0458cbb02c6fdf50a311260367b078ed3f59bbb)

Comment: This line `if text[i].lower() or text[i].upper():`  in the loop of counting letters was also wrong and I changed it as you said and it works now. Thanks a lot. 

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to mention that. Any other queries you can ask me.